# How to select NIB for view controller in xcode4?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, xcode4

I have created a universal window based application in xcode 4. Additionally I created a `FirstViewController` class with a `FirstViewController.xib` file.

I dragged a `Navigation Controller` to the objects panel for the `MainWindow_iPhone.xib`. I want the root controller to be the FirstViewController so I selected it in the custom class property.

I now want the view to be loaded from `FirstViewController.xib` but I can't select it in the NIB name selector, it just is not listed there. When I type it in it says that it is not intended to be there.

The strange thing is that exactly this procedure worked for me in xcode 3.2.6

Any ideas?

[image]

Comment: I am so dreading Xcode 4. Wish I could help you here, but I've/I'm having the exact same problem.

Comment: Hi, hope you read this. Did you find the answer to this problem yet?, i'm having the same problem here. Regards, Pieter

Comment: @Overbeeke I edited the answer below with additional information, hope that helps ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"When I type it in it says that it is not intended to be there."

Hang on, isn't it the case that this is because: **it is not intended to be there** ..!?

There were many heinous problems in the ancient XCodes that could lead to a mess, XCode4 fortunately prevents said issues.

Just to be clear, FirstViewController is a subclass of what?  There must be some problem, because it works fine.

We have had utterly no problem whatsoever dragging custom classes, into an xib, to have them instantiated, I just did a couple this minute to triple-check - no problem!!

Comment: I recreated my FirstViewController and now it works, magic :D The NIB is still not listed, however it works

Comment: jep it's UIViewController. It seems there was something wrong with the outlets.